# how to install chroot dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, arm, chroot

there is ubuntu img which is made by rootstock
to run in ARM architecture
but I can't chroot the img
many people say this is dependencies problem
if I do not have the loader and/or shared libraries available to make,
what am I supposed to do?

I have ubuntu img and I can't chroot the img
so I have no idea how to add or install
such a libraries and loader inside img

I don't know how to install them(below)

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/make
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff95fff000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc97d557000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc97d1f6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc97cfd9000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc97d761000)
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to chroot() to an ARM file-system on an x86?  If this is the case, you can't use chroot() directly because the binaries in the target file-system are for a different architecture.  You may want to look at [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org).